# How to add a column from df1 to df2 if it not present in df2, else do nothing

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 data frame from a basic web scrape using Pandas (below). The second table has less columns than the first, and I need to concat the dataframes. I have been manually inserting columns for a while but seeing as they change frequently I would like to have a function that can assess the columns in df2, check whether they are all in df2, and if not, add the column, with the data from df2.

```
import pandas as pd 

link = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_polling_for_the_next_French_presidential_election'
df = pd.read_html(link,header=0)

df1 = df[1]
df1 = df1.drop([0])
df1 = df1.drop('Abs.',axis=1)

df2 = df[2]
df2 = df2.drop([0])
df2 = df2.drop(['Abs.'],axis=1)
```

Many thanks,

Comment: How do you concatenate the two tables? Have you tried `pd.concat([df1, df2])`? That should do the trick.

Comment: Ah so simple! Yeah I that works, I think I was trying to overcomplicate it :)

Answer (score 1):

@divingTobi's answer:

`pd.concat([df1, df2])` does the trick.